# How do I scan elements of a 2d array under certain conditions, when using recursion in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array filled with non-negative numbers.
one cell in particular is equal to -1 (for example, the bottom right corner in the array below is -1).

I have to return the minimum number of steps (starting from arr[0][0] only) to get to the -1.

The thing is:
You can think of every number in the array as a height of a rooftop.

The difference between cell values when moving in any direction is either "climbing" or "going down":

For example, moving in any direction from a cell with the value 5, to a cell with the value 3 is considered "going down", and the difference is 2.

For example, moving in any direction from a cell with the value 1, to a cell with the value 2, is considered "climbing", and the difference is -1.

If the difference between cell values while "climbing" is smaller than -1,
and the difference between cell values while " going down" is bigger than 2,
There are no legal options to move inside the array, and the recursive method will return -1.

The only exception is: if the value of the "neighbor" cell from any direction is the -1 we are searching for, we can immediately go there without having to consider the difference between the current cell and the "neighbor" cell.

If there is no valid path that starts in arr[0][0] and can find "-1" in the array, the recursive method should return -1. If there is a valid path the recursive method returns the minimum number of steps.

```
        System.out.println("[2,  0,  1,  2,  3]");
        System.out.println("[2,  3,  5,  5,  4]");
        System.out.println("[8,  5, -1,  8,  7]");
        System.out.println("[3,  4,  7,  2,  4]");
        System.out.println("[2,  4,  3,  1, -1]");
```

I didn't manage to solve it without running into "out of bounds" errors, and logic errors.
For example, what shall I do when the difference between any direction while "climbing" or "going down" is the same?

So that's what I have tried:

```
 public static int prince(int[][]drm, int i, int j){
        return prince(drm, 0,0, 1);
    }

 private static int prince(int[][]drm, int i, int j, int steps)
    {
        if(i> drm.length-1 || j>drm[drm.length-1].length) // out of bounds
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(drm[i][j] == -1) // is the current cell is "-1"
        {
            return steps;
        }
        if(i< drm.length-1)
        {
            if(drm[i+1][j] == -1) // if the neighbor below the cell is the "-1"
            {
                return steps + 1;
            }
        }
        if(j<drm[drm.length-1].length) // if the right neighbor of the cell is the "-1"
        {
            if(drm[i][j+1] == -1)
            {
                return steps + 1;
            }
        }
        if(i>0) { // if the neighbor above the cell is the "-1"
            if (drm[i - 1][j] == 1) {
                return steps + 1;
            }
        }
        if(j>0) // if the left neighbor of the cell is the "-1"
        {
            if (drm[i][j-1] == 1) {
                return steps + 1;
            }
        }
```

so checking the neighbors to see if they're equal to -1 is ok. but I'm not sure how to construct the next part, that actually contains the recursive call.

I wanted to scan the array horizontally in each row, to the rightmost point, and when it gets there - to make j=0 again, go down a row (if possible) and make the number of steps as same as it would be if we would down initially instead of right.

Something amount those lines:

```
 if(j == drm[drm.length-1].length) // if we got to the end of the row (rightmost column)
        {
            if(i < drm.length-1){ // and we can go down without going out of bounds
                int downDiff = drm[i][j] - drm[i+1][j];
                if(!(downDiff > 2) && !(downDiff < -1)){ // if the difference when going down is valid
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                    steps -= drm.length - 2;
                } else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(j<drm[drm.length-1].length) { // if we didn't get to the end of the row (not in the rightmost column)
            int rightDiff = drm[i][j] - drm[i][j+1];
            if(rightDiff > 2 || rightDiff < -1) // if right difference is not valid
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return prince(drm, i, j+1, steps+1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

so if you have any ideas, or smarter algorithms/approaches to this question I will be more than glad for any comments.